# IE8 stacking and squashes entire site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Quick site designed and developed for a local little league baseball team.

IE7 support not required. Site works perfect in current browsers.

IE8 happens to be completely destroying every containing element though in a really weird manor that is causing the entire site to stack on top of itself.

Any immediate ideas or suggestions?

http://agawamgatorsbaseball.com/dev/

P.S. Next time I will use http://lint.brihten.com/html/ before jumping to the boards.

Comment: The image slider won't load on IE9 nor on IE8 ... I have the same problem with my site that the image slider won't load. +1 Waiting for Answer too

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Yeah I wonder why that is.. IE8 is now working with the image slider but no go for IE9

Comment: @Miro figured it out. Change your jquery to ver. 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you have an open 'div' in your header:

```
<header>
    <h1>AGAWAM GATORS BASEBALL</h1>
    <div class="contact_us">
        <p>Team Manager</p>
        <h2>Steve Moccio<br />
        moccio6@comcast.net</h2>
    </header>
```

Try checking for any other unclosed tags.

Comment: Let me know if it worked, if not- I will try to think about other things that could mess up IE rendering.

Comment: OOOF. Yeah... you were right. Need to check my code better next time.     Thanks mate.